# Click on field in new window

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In selenium webdriver, I am trying to click on a field in new window, but I keep getting error as

```
 "Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: .//*[@id='UpdatePanel1']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55"
```

Here's the piece of code I have written. Kindly help

```
public class AE_Shipment {

public void AE_Shipment1() throws InterruptedException 
{
    MyClass1 M1= new MyClass1();
    WebDriver w1 = M1.w;
    w1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='MainMenu-mI001']")).click();
    w1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='MainMenu-mI001-sM-mI001']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]")).click();
    w1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='MainMenu-mI001-sM-mI001-sM-mI000']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]")).click();
    w1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='MainMenu-mI001-sM-mI001-sM-mI000-sM-mI000']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]")).click();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(w1, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='UpdatePanel1']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td")));

    w1.findElement(By.id("ButSearch")).click();
}
```

Update: I have tried switching to the new window using the code below but I get the same error.

```
String parentHandle = w1.getWindowHandle(); // get the current window handle 
w1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ButSearch']")).click(); 
for (String winHandle : w1.getWindowHandles()) 
{ 
    w1.switchTo().window(winHandle); // switch focus of WebDriver to the next found window handle (that's your newly opened window) 
}
```

Comment: The element is in new window? Have you tried to switch window? Have you tried increasing the waiting time?

Comment: Yes, switch window, waiting time.. everything has been tried out

Comment: Your code doesn't account for switching window. Include that and then try for another element and see if you are getting an error or not.May be the xpath you're trying to use is not correct.

Comment: String parentHandle = w1.getWindowHandle(); // get the current window handle
  w1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ButSearch']")).click();  

  for (String winHandle : w1.getWindowHandles()) 
  {
      w1.switchTo().window(winHandle); // switch focus of WebDriver to the next found window handle (that's your newly opened window)
  }

Comment: this is what i tried still same error

Comment: @Sharvari - I've added your code above to the question and formatted it.

Answer (score 1):

We have to use `SwitchTo()` functions, to click an element on new window which opens from your original webDriver instance. Following code might work.

```
public class AE_Shipment {

public void AE_Shipment1() throws InterruptedException 
{
    MyClass1 M1= new MyClass1();
    WebDriver w1 = M1.w;

 // get the current window handle
 String patentWindow = w1.getWindowHandle();

    w1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='MainMenu-mI001']")).click();
    w1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='MainMenu-mI001-sM-mI001']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]")).click();
    w1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='MainMenu-mI001-sM-mI001-sM-mI000']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]")).click();
    w1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='MainMenu-mI001-sM-mI001-sM-mI000-sM-mI000']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]")).click();

 // switch focus of WebDriver to the next found window handle (that's your newly opened window)
 for (String newWindow : w1.getWindowHandles()) {
  w1.switchTo().window(newWindow); 
 }

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(w1, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='UpdatePanel1']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td")));

 // click the element on new window
    w1.findElement(By.id("ButSearch")).click();

 // close newly opened window when done with it. (If required)
 w1.close(); 

 // switch back to the original window
 w1.switchTo().window(patentWindow); 
}
```

Comment: Tried, but still same error Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.id: ButSearch
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'

Comment: Can you check in firebug console, if the selectors are right? As I have verified above mentioned code in website and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the way you have mentioned your code.

You've mentioned that your element is in new window-I am assuming the waiting needs to be done once you have switched the window.

So you need to place 
the wait condition after your window handling code-

```
String parentHandle = w1.getWindowHandle(); // get the current window handle 
w1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ButSearch']")).click(); 
for (String winHandle : w1.getWindowHandles()) 
{ 

 w1.switchTo().window(winHandle); // switch focus of WebDriver to the next found window handle (that's your newly opened window) 

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(w1, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='UpdatePanel1']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td")));

//do whatever you want to do here
}
```

This should do away with the wait condition. And also try increasing the wait time to around 50 seconds to see if you still get the time out exception.

Also I would want to check the xpath- if the exception still persists. Try using any other locater (like CSS Selector) or a different element to wait for to see if the wait condition is working correctly.

Comment: there was some problem while posting the comment, the code written was as below, still the error persists..

Comment: String parentHandle = w1.getWindowHandle(); // get the current window handle
  w1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ButSearch']")).click();  

  for (String winHandle : w1.getWindowHandles()) 
  {
      w1.switchTo().window(winHandle); // switch focus of WebDriver to the next found window handle (that's your newly opened window)
  }
  
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(w1, 50);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ButSearch']")));
  
  w1.findElement(By.id("ButSearch")).click();

Comment: Please specify the exception that you are getting when posting comment.

Comment: You are searching for the wrong element inside the window handle. Search for the (.//*[@id='UpdatePanel1']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td) inside the child window handle

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"txtShipmentNo"}
Command duration or timeout: 10 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: This exception happened at another element not the one you listed above

Comment: Only the xpath/ id was changed from ButSearch to txtShipmentNo as I have been changing fields, exception error remains same

Answer (score 0):

Just you are traversing through all the window handles using a for loop.
First print the parent window handle.

```
System.out.println(w1.getWindowHandle());
```

Take all window handles use `toArray()` to convert to `Object[] a` array.

```
Object[] a=w1.getWindowHandles().toArray();
```

Then print the window handles of all the windows opened using for loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
    System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

Now identify in which order windows are printed. (It will be in such an order, that the latest window opened will be at last index of the array elements).

Just get the web element at last index of the array `a` to switch to it.

```
String latestWindow=(String) a[a.length-1];//Typea casting from Object type to String is required
w1.switchTo().window(latestWindow);
```

Now, you can do whatever the things you would like to do on the new window you switched to.

Comment: tried the code you suggested, still no luck, error remains same 'unable to locate element'

Comment: Can I have the link of the webpage you are working on...

Comment: Its the company app, wont be able to share the link

Comment: Can I have any snapshots of html source and webpage?

Comment: HTML code for the field I am trying to click: -color: #ffffff;">
<iframe id="DocFrame" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="Modules/FrgtFwding/ShipmentJobsList.aspx?Mode=A&_cb_=1454409492590" scrolling="no" name="DocFrame">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1">
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
<link id="winShowDtl_style" href="/Logisys2_39/wdstyles/blue/blue.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="StyleSheet">

Comment: It looks like you forgot switching to Frame called "DocFrame". You just add one more statement before clicking on that element. That is `w1.switchTo().frame("DocFrame");` Then write the line of statment to findout the element and click on that element after switching to the DocFrame iframe.

Comment: Already tried SwitchTo().frame: w1.switchTo().frame(w1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ButSearch']")));
  Thread.sleep(500);
  // click the element on new window
     w1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ButSearch']")).click();

Comment: What are the possible reasons for error for 'element not found' in selenium webdriver coz I have tried all possible codes and still same error persists

Comment: The "ButSearch" id is an element id in new window opened? Then you are switching in the wrong way. just switch to that using above statement which I gave. After switching to that particular frame using the frame name "DocFrame", try to find out the element with "ButSearch" id. Then click on it. Please don't forget to follow the answer I wrote. Follow the instructions I gave in the answer and then use switchto frame.

Comment: The possible reasons for that error is the element you are looking for is not available in the webpage the w1 object referring.

Comment: When I login into the app, i already perform an action through code-- click on menu say Transport--Export, now the page is loaded and now I have to click on some field say 'Search' in Export page... here the error "Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"id"}" is thrown